# Does a continuous function $R^k \to R$ always map a $k$-cell to an interval?

Tags: real-analysis

Does the following generalization of the intermediate value theoreom hold?

Let $f: R^k \to R$ be continuous. Then $f$ maps a $k$-cell to an interval.

Can we be more general and extend this to connected subsets of $R^k$?

Comment: Continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets. The $k$-cell is connected, and the connected sets of $\mathbb{R}$ are intervals.

Comment: This is what I thought.